# Can two associated models share the same join name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, polymorphism, associations

I have a `User` model that can acquire gift certificates from a `CardSignup` model they create.

However, I also would like to give out free gift certificates from a seperate model called `GiftConversion`

My models are set up as so :

**User.rb**

```
has_many :conversions, :foreign_key => :converted_by, :class_name => "CardSignup"
has_many :conversions, :foreign_key => :converted_by, :class_name => "GiftConversion"
```

**CardSignup.rb**

```
belongs_to                     :converted_by, :class_name => "User"
```

**GiftConversion**

```
belongs_to                     :converted_by, :class_name => "User"
```

In this way, what I want to do is type `User.find(x).conversions`, and it would return both the `CardSignup` model and the `GiftConversion` model so long as their foreign_key `:converted_by` is associated to that user model.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work so properly. Instead the compiler just grabs the later statement. In this case, `GiftConversion`, and only allows that to be recognized as a `User.find(x).conversions`.

Does anyone know how I can have the `User` model share both models under the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably have a custom association which connects both tables with a custom SQL statement using `UNION`, or something like that, but I don't recommend it since you have two models which represent something pretty similar, but not identical – a great use case for single-table inheritance.

The way I would do it is to have one single table for both `CardSignup` and `GiftConversion` and use single-table inheritance to connect the two models, so the common table would include a `type` column which specifies whether it's a `CardSignup` or `GiftConversion`.

See here under "Single Table Inheritance" for more information:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: I really can't make heads or tails of this. But it seems like a great idea.

Comment: This article explains it well: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Comment: It still doesn't explain how to coalesce three different models in this 2 to 1 / 1 to 2 polymorphic association.

Comment: I looked at that article 16 times over, copied the code. Its a bunk example.

Comment: You define 3 models, `CardSignup`, `GiftConversion` and a parent of those two, let's say `Conversion`. The 2 child models inherit from `Conversion`, not from `ActiveRecord::Base` like every other model. Then you generate a migration to create the DB table only for `Conversion`, not for the others. This table needs to include a `type` (string) column which is (automatically) set to either `CardSignup` or `GiftConversion`. Rails will automatically read that type to decide which Model the object belongs to.

Comment: Actually, now that I read it again, the article kind of assumes that this is clear, sorry.

Comment: Maybe this one is better http://joemcglynn.wordpress.com/2009/12/12/rails-single-table-inheritance-part-2/